# Why it connected continuously whether the path is correct or wrong

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, qt5

I've written the following code to connect with sqlite database file .

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("c://database.db");
if(!db.open())
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Failed to connect to database");
else
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Connected.");
```

When change the correct path another wrong path (ex: `c://datafile.db` or `c:database.db`), it remain prints `Connected.` text.

[image]

**Notice:** If the database file does not exists, or the correct path changed to another wrong path, it will create an empty database file into the wrong path.

**Is there is any problem in my code to prints `Connected` all time?**

Comment: `(ex: c://datafile.db or c:database.db)` - are you sure they're wrong paths?  Many Windows functions accept slashes in place of backslashes, and if you don't specify a path it'll use the current working directory.  Perhaps try something like "XXXX" if you want to be sure it's an error....

Comment: @TonyD: I'm done the following `db.setDatabaseName("");`, and still show me `connected` text. I'm surprised.

Comment: You're not calling this code multiple times are you, or opening a connection elsewhere?  The [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377590/sqldatabase-setdatabasename-doesnt-work-in-qt) implies that having the same connection name (in your case the default) can lead to an earlier-opened db connection being reused.

Comment: @TonyD: I have the following message after apply the answer which in the link `QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'dbConn' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.`

Comment: @TonyD: I noticed something strange, If the database file does not exists, or the correct path changed to another wrong path, it will create an empty database file into the wrong path. Is it possible that this is the cause of the problem, and how to solve it ?

Comment: I've seen some similar code check that the file exists before trying to open the database... maybe that's the best way to avoid accidentally creating a new database at that path...?

Comment: Was I able to help you with your question? If so please leave the best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQLite then it will *always* attempt to create the database file if it can. This may not be what you want -- for example, if you need to use data from a pre-existing database. What you should do is verify that the *file exists on disk* before trying to open.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

QFile file ("c:/database.db");
if (file.exists()) {
  if(!db.open()) {
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Failed to connect to database");
  }
  else {
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Connected.");
  }
}
else {
  ui->table->setText("Database does not exist!");
}
```

Note that the forward slash `/` works for any platform, and is less confusing than having to escape with the `\` character. To have better portability you should probably replace the hard coded `C:/` with something from `QDir::root()` or `QDir::drives()`.

Comment: THIS is the answer you are looking for

Comment: I was hope to give me more detail about mention `QDir::root()` and `QDir::drives()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot it in the documentation, but some [mailing list threads](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20430-qt-how-to-connect-to-sqlite-db-file) suggest that `QSqlDatabase::open` will *always* return true because it will create an empty database if there is no database at the given path.  Note, as others have pointed out, that C://database.db is likely to be a valid path - most C++ libraries accept '/' as a path separator on Windows.  It is also fairly common for libraries to convert paths you give them to 'canonical paths', which will usually involve cleaning up things like extra path separators and missing path separators after a drive name.